# Particle hair Glitch when rendering

Tags: rendering, particles

Is there a way to render this without the hair glitch?

[image]

Render settings:

[image]
[image]

File link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NNG_T-4PLe6EkcgeJOH88O0jk3T_NT8K/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can u share the blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: I added the file

Comment: the textures are missing but to me it looks okay when I render it (frame 180)

Comment: Maybe because my computer is not strong enough to render that fast?